# Second build in VB.NET project always fails

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

I've started encountering a weird behavior of VS2010 when building VB.NET projects:

The first build succeeds, I do a small change (e.g. add comment) and the second build just fails with errors I don't understand:

```
Error   1   "obj\x86\Debug\<Project Name>.exe;obj\x86\Debug\<Project Name>.exe" is an invalid value for the "OutputAssembly" parameter of the "Vbc" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".   <Project Name>
Error   2   The "exists" function only accepts a scalar value, but its argument "@(IntermediateAssembly)" evaluates to "obj\x86\Debug\<Project Name>.exe;obj\x86\Debug\<Project Name>.exe" which is not a scalar value. <Project Name>
```

Sometimes a different error appears with the very same project:

```
Error   1   The target "CompileRdlFiles" does not exist in the project. <Project Name>
```

When I close the solution, reopen and rebuild, it succeeds again or fails with different error such as:

```
Error   1   The target "EntityDeploy" does not exist in the project.    BetterThumbnailBrowser
```

This happens with freshly create VB.NET projects as well.

The projects are always Windows Forms Applications.

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering this same issue in all versions of VS (2010, 2012, 2013) on my work machine lately too.  I have been unable to determine the cause, either by my own investigation or by searching on the web.  I tried uninstalling all three versions and reinstalling but the issue persists.

From the reading I did do, I found that it relates to a corrupt RESX file.  As a result, I was able to come up with a workaround.  After trying to build and encountering that error, I click the Show All Files button in the Solution Explorer, expand the node for the form and then delete the RESX file.  The project will then build and run successfully.  Even after making further changes, the error does not return.  I'm not sure whether adding more forms creates the issue again but you can test that.